# Capture Youtube player event in GWT app

Tags: events, gwt, youtube

I'm building an app using GWT with an embedded Youtube player. I intend to do some stuff when the video ends. How do I capture that event?

By the way, I'm using gwt2swf to embed the player.

**Reference:**
[gwt2swf](http://code.google.com/p/gwt2swf/)
[Youtube player events](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this project that does what I want.

http://code.google.com/p/hotforcode/

Will look into the source code to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering your question specifically, but seemingly this BST Player project does that  (bridge a flash video player and GWT).

Hope it helps.
http://code.google.com/p/bst-player/

If it doesn't help, I believe you'll have to find out if the Flash component you are using has javascript callbacks, and capture them through GWT's javascript native invocation.